# Why "undefined is null or not an object"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand this code example.  I've scrubbed the URL for posting purposes, but I'm reasonably certain that's not the issue.....
I'm lookin at the Script/Debug F12 , and the console says:

**LOG: A**

**'undefined' is null or not an object**
at this line "A().then(B()).then(C()).then(D());"

I also stripped the 2 second delay & put an alert(), same error.
...lil' help?

```
<script>
 function A() {
     console.log("A");
 }

 function B() {
     console.log("B");
     var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
         clearInterval(intervalId);
         console.log("Section: ");
         deferred.resolve();
     }, 2000);
     console.log("B and 2 sec");

 }

 function C() {
     console.log("C");
 }

 function D() {
     console.log("D");
 }

 function dMain() {

     A().then(B()).then(C()).then(D());
 }
 </script>

 <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Generate Exam" onclick="javascript:dMain();" />
```

Comment: There are so many problems in this code it's hard to know where to start. What's `deferred.resolve();` for you ? You should probably have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Comment: `A()` calls `console.log` which returns undefined. You can't call a function on undefined.

Comment: You have a `deferred` variable you never created. I think there's the problem.

Comment: THanks for the quick responses....while I see the pieces of your comments in ssube's answer, I needed his code examples because I have so little base-knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `A` does not return anything, so attempting to use the return value is equivalent to `undefined.then()` and undefined is not an object.

What you likely want is to use some type of deferred, likely [jQuery's version](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). There are a few good examples [on their site](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/), so you might look into something like:

```
function A() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    console.log("A");
    def.resolve();
    return def;
}
```

This will return a deferred object, which happens to already be resolved.

For your `A().then(B()).then(C()).then(D())` line, you likely want to call each function when the previous one resolves. Your current code requires every function return a deferred object, but also calls them all at the beginning. I'm not sure the best way to handle this (depends on where you're going with it), but something like this might work:

```
A().then(function () { 
    B().then(function() {
        C().then(function() {
            D();
        });
    });
});
```

Each function will be called after the previous deferred has been resolved, presumably after all the waits and intervals have expired.

Comment: THank you....THat works swimmingly; it was a combo of not getting a Deffered var built & returned from each function, and using the the curly brackets in the sequential call.